# cannot upload image to api using dio in flutter

Tags: node.js, api, flutter, dio

i have used this code to pick image from gallery in mobile, and then upload it to the server using api, with other data, every thing works good, all data uploaded successfully except image, i don't know what is the problem, specially even image uploaded successfully when use Postman... this my code in flutter side:

```
TextEditingController  namec = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController  descc = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController  pricec = TextEditingController();
   File image;
   String imgUrl;


   getImage() async{
     var imageIns =  await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
     setState(() {
       image = File(imageIns.path);
       imgUrl = imageIns.path;
     });
   }
   /////////////////////
  uploadImage() async {
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "name" : namec.text,
      "file" : image,
      "desc" : descc.text,
      "price" : pricec.text,
      "cat" : widget.cid
    });
    var res = await dio.post(
        "http://192.168.43.106:3000/service", data: formData);
    final data = json.decode(res.data);
```

and this in node.js side (api) for insert data including image:

```
insertServices: async (req, res)=>{
   // var path = req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    const result = await new SERVICES({
    name : req.body.name,
    file :  req.file != null ? req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, '/') : "PATH",
    desc : req.body.desc,
    price : req.body.price,
    cat : req.body.cat
    }).save()
    res.json({
        message: "success",
        id : result._id,
        name : result.name,
        file : result.file,
        desc : result.desc,
        price : result.price
    })
    },

  and i am using (multer) middle ware to upload the image,
```

and this is the error in the server side when i try to upload image by flutter app (with postmant no error):

```
::ffff:192.168.43.1 - - [08/Jul/2020:11:43:28 +0000] "GET /PATH HTTP/1.1" 404 143
(node:15612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at insertServices (G:\eservices\logic\service.js:67:22)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (G:\eservices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at compression (G:\eservices\node_modules\compression\index.js:220:5)
(node:15612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15612) [DEP0018] DeprecationWa
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar app to upload images from gallery, here is an example of it:

```
List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
```

I use [multi_image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) to pick multiple images at once and after filling the `images` List I use this code to upload them:

```
Dio dio = new Dio();
  var items = [];
  for (var item in images) {
  ByteData byteData = await item.getThumbByteData(800, 800);
  List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

  MultipartFile i =
  MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    imageData,
    filename: item.name,
  );
  items.add(i);
}
      
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({"userfile": items});
Response response = await dio.post(phpEndPoint, data: formData);
if(response.statusCode==200) //success
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure what code is in the backend.